Azure Function Python V2 Model - Cannot reference from Azure Logic App
When creating a new Azure Function Python V2 without changing any part of the VS Code generated code, this function cannot be then reference from Azure Logic App due to error: Cannot be called from a logic app. It must not have a custom route
The function source code is the default one from VS Code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="test_http")
def test_http(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )`

I tried:

Change @app.route(route="test_http") to @app.route(route="req")
Change @app.route(route="test_http") to @app.route(methods=["POST"])

Nothing does change.
I compared with a default function created in C#, and both have the same URL structure: https://<function-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/<function-name>
I cannot find docs on Microsoft site or if, in general, Azure Function in python cannot be used in Azure Logic Apps.

Azure Functions V2 model are only available in Standard Plan of logic apps but not in Consumption plan of logic apps:
You can use Azure Functions connector:
In Consumption Plan:

You cannot find functions inside the function app.
In Standard Plan:

Then clicked on create new and then saved the logic apps:

Output:

My function :

My function app code is basic as yours.

You can get around this by setting your route to the following:
@app.route(route="")


Without a doubt, the Azure Functions is the worst service I have ever seen  across all Azure, GCP and AWS. Microsoft should be ashamed of launching such a poorly documented and flakey service.
I've spent countless hours fighting vague error after vague error.
Dropping support of V1 Python apps (InternalServerError) (this previously worked fine)

Lack of support for in terraform for V2 models (not really Microsofts fault tbh)
Having to have a very specific configuration to even allow function apps to be invoked by logic apps.

No resources of this type found under this subscription.

Not allowing custom routes with logic app invocation

Then there are issues with logic app providers themselves, such as the RSS component, which double encodes URLs, so I have to go into code view, manually remove an encoding, and re-save!
Although the above workaround will do the job for now, I have no doubt that Microsoft will make more changes and break things again. Honestly, this service is terrible compared to AWS Lambda.
